# const iterator dependent on begin() function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator

I tried to simplify the situation as good as possible.

Basically I have a class that represents a dynamic `Array` (here shown as `class Array` with size 4) and secondly a class which is a HashMap, and has an `Array of Arrays` as a member (here represented by `class Bar`).

Both classes implement `begin()` and `end()` so you can use a foreach loop to iterate over all elements.

The iterator type of `Array` is simply `T*` and `const T*` for the const variant.
For `Bar` there is a special `class Iterator`, which correctly iterates through all members of the `Array<Array<T>>`.
You should now have a look at the classes I provided, so you know what exactly I'm talking about.

> But now there is a problem when I call `bar.begin()` on a `const Bar` object

---

The Iterator class determines the `ArrayIterator` and `ElementIterator` types automatically (via decltype of T::begin()), because in my real application almost everything is templated and that's why I don't know the exact type in advance.

I figured out the problem is that `decltype(((T*)nullptr)->begin())` always chooses the non-const begin() function of T, which absolutely makes sense since I haven't written `(const T*)nullptr`.

If I now call it from a const context, it will fail to assign a `const T*` like `data.last().end()` to the internal `T*` from the decltype which actually should be a `const T*`.

I can workaround the problem by declaring a second class `ConstIterator` which does everything exactly like the non-const one, but uses `(const Array<T>*)nullptr` and `(const T*)nullptr` inside the decltype statements.

So what can I do without copying the whole Bar::Iterator class?

---

Simplified code:

```
template<class T>
class Array
{
    T data[4];

    T last() { return data[3]; }


    T* begin()             { return data; };
    T* end()               { return data + 4; };

    const T* begin() const { return data; };
    const T* end() const   { return data + 4; };
}

template<class T>
class Bar
{
    class Iterator
    {
        using ArrayIterator = decltype(((Array<T>*)nullptr)->begin());
        using ElementIterator = decltype(((T*)nullptr)->begin());

        Iterator(const ArrayIterator& beg, const ArrayIterator& end)
        {
            //initialize the iterator to the first element of the first array
            //(and rembember end)
        };

        Iterator(const ElementIterator& cur)
        {
            //initialize the iterator to the current element
        };

        //++ will iterate go to next element and eventually jump to the next array.
        //== returns true if the current element is the same
    };

    Array<T> data;

    Iterator begin()       { return Iterator(data.begin(), data.end()); };
    Iterator end()         { return Iterator(data.last().end()); };

    Iterator begin() const { return Iterator(data.begin(), data.end()); };
    Iterator end() const   { return Iterator(data.last().end()); };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you will have to implement `ConstIterator` class. See, for example, the standard containers like `vector` or `list`, you have both `iterator` and `const_iterator` there, and they're different classes. Const correctness is hard sometimes. However, you can get away with code duplication by using templates or const_cast (see, for example, Scott Myers *Effective C++*)

Comment: Don't use const_cast for that.